# Как управлять зависимостями Ruby библиотек?

Tags: ruby, gems, bundler

Существуют две разных библиотеки.

1. github.com/foo/super
2. github.com/bar/super-puper

Ставятся через Bundler/Gemfile.

```rb
# Gemfile
gem 'super'
gem 'super-puper'
```

Однако, вызываются в коде по одному имени.

```rb
# main.rb
require 'super' # for github.com/foo/super
require 'super' # for github.com/bar/super-puper
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в коде выбрать, какую именно библиотеку вызывать, если имя для вызова у них одинаковое, но источники разные.

Answer (score 0):

```
irb> Gem.loaded_specs["mygem"].full_require_paths
=> ["/Users/me/.gem233/gems/mygem-1.7.1/lib"]

irb> require "#{Gem.loaded_specs["mygem"].full_require_paths.first}/mygem"
=> true
```